# Android : Buttons in the background Activity of a 'Dialog' is active?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-theme

I have an Activity which has an 'OK' button. And I have an 'Edit' button which will open a Dialog (`theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"`). When I am in the EditDialog, I can see the OK button in the background Activity, and I can press that, and it the press is getting registered.

Is there a way to disable the background Activity actions when a Dialog is open? i.e. I want to modify things in the Dialog alone.

Edit: Adding a sample code which shows this behaviour.
Main Activity:

```
public class DialogTestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private final String TAG = "DialogTest.main";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button_open)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ok)).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_ok:
            Log.w(TAG, "OK Button Pressed!");
            break;
        case R.id.button_open:
            Log.d(TAG, "Opening new Window.");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestDialog.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

TestDialog 'dialog':

```
public class TestDialog extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_dialog);

        LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".DialogTestActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".TestDialog"
    android:label="@string/dialog_label"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" >
</activity>
```

With the above code, when the TestDialog was open, the Button Press on the background Activity were registered - `OK Button Pressed!` will be logged.

Comment: When a `Dialog` is in the foreground, nothing in the underlying activity should be clickable. If you can create a sample project demonstrating your problem, I would be interested in seeing it.

Comment: Sample code given above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this is not a dialog. This is a dialog-themed activity. A dialog inherits from `Dialog`.

Second, your use of `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` is giving you precisely the behavior that you do not want. Delete this line of code, and things should work better.

Comment: Creating a Dialog with `this.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` resolved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Just for information from API 11 its changed to setFinishOnTouchOutside(), so this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false); will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the underlying `Activity` should be clickable when a `Dialog` is in the foreground (this is how `Dialog`s in Android work). If you are able to interact with the underlying `Activity` when the `Dialog` is open, then there is probably something wrong with your implementation.

Edit:

Remove this line and all should work:

```
this.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: I have attached the code above. My requirement is that, if I am in the dialog, it shouldn't exit when I touch somewhere outside the Dialog (which is the default behaviour) and the background activity shouldn't register any calls. I understand that something is wrong with the Flag I am setting. Appreciate your help if you could suggest the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your Activity is opened with set Dialog theme use code below

`setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);`